# How to do roll back using chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have seen a resource called "deploy" resource. But i don't know how to do roll back using that resource.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html#actions)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html) (as @tensibai recommends. You'll see the resource has a :rollback action:

> :rollback Roll an application back to the previous release.